# Will aws s3 sync stops if I close down the shell from where it runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

- running aws s3 sync s3://bucket_a s3://bucket_b
- running it from my machine's iterm shell console
- bucket_A size is 1.5TB
- iterm is having high mem pressure
- because of this I'm unable to keep using my laptop

question:  if I close my CLI window - this is, without sending ctrl-c to the command - will the sync process stops?

To me, the aws s3 sync instruction has already been received by aws, so it shouldn't harm...

Comment: What about using [AWS DataSync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync/faqs/#Transferring_to_and_from_Amazon_S3) ?

Comment: Give it a try, and let us know what you discover! You might need to use [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) to keep the session running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just for every other person running the same question, the response is:  yes, the process does end if the shell window is closed.

Why? Because the command issues GET and PUT for each object to be synced hence, when the shell is killed, the active commands too.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this would be to launch an EC2 instance to handle the sync command, attach the same role that you used for the IAM user to perform the transfer to the EC2, launch the sync command as user data for the EC2.